# working out a checksum of mixed characters

Tags: java, character, ascii, checksum

I'm trying to work out a checksum from a string such as this `"[Y-34-]"` the checksum should add up all the characters in the string. I'm struggling to understand how to add up numbers to letters and other character.

Do characters as [,Y and - need to be converted into their ascii? values? in that case. How would I convert them and then add them to the number?

thanks

Comment: We don't know what conversion you want to perform on the characters in order to get them into some form you can add up. Are you trying to comply with an existing checksum algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
int sum=0;
   for (int i=0;i<string.length;i++){
      sum=sum+(int)string.charAt(i);
    }
```

This works because internally a char is stored as a number which you can easily add up and get an int.